My ether stuck on contract possible get back
my ethereum got stuck on contract address: 0x217171acD4c1fA26aD7C79271353BF690BC89Ad7
there any way to get mack manusak  _manualSwap didn't work please help.

I wonder why you removed transferOwnership function which can be your last hope... I tried but it seems you have to accept that you lost that 1 ETH

you no way get back?

Did you try calling openTrading? I think uniswapV2Router isn't initialized and that variable is required to execute manualSwap. Only the taxWallet address 0x084194e136439dab2F92b50cD83a3F7043c0BAA7 would be able to withdraw from the contract.
